# A question regarding Vitali Covering Covering Lemma

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let f be an increasing function on the closed, bounded interval [a, b]. Define $$E_{\alpha}=\{ x\in(a,b) | \bar{D}f(x) \geq \ \alpha \}$$
Choose $\alpha^{'} \in (0, \alpha)$. Let $F$ be the
collection of closed, bounded intervals $[c, d]$ contained in $(a, b)$ for which $f (d) - f(c) \geq\alpha^{'}(d - c)$. Since $\bar{D}f(x) > \alpha$ on $E_{\alpha}$, $F$ is a Vitali covering of $E_{\alpha}$.

Why is F a Vitali covering of $E_{\alpha}$?

Comment: Can you give the definition of $\overline{D}f(x)$?

Comment: See this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3156190/72031